# pdf doc. pagination, using 'page' parameter, in Chrome and Safari Web browsers

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, safari

I would appreciate help on getting the 'page' parameter working in the Chrome and Safari Web Browsers - i.e when used as URL.

For instance given the URL: myFile.PDF#Page=21
This opens up to the specified page - page 21 - of the PDF document in the ff. browsers:
Firefox: version 3.6.15
IE 8.0.6001.18702
IE 6.0.2900.
Opera 11.01

but not* in chrome and safari:
Safari: 5.0.4
Chrome: 10.0.6
*i.e it opens the first page of the document, and not page 21 directly.

I gather Safari and chrome have their own PDF rendering engine hence ignore the 'page' parameter.

Has anyone any success, links or resources on getting the page reference working in either chrome or safari?

Cheers.

Comment: You may want to pose this question at [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: `MyFile.PDF#page=21` works for me in Chrome 30.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try with ?page=21 (small p). Maybe that will work. If not you could file a bug report.

Comment: doesn't work in chrome. I'm yet to try that in Safari. Cheers

Comment: YOu can do a search for acrolink.pdf (http://bit.ly/h3Nswt). PDF plugin manufacturers may not be aware of these recommendations from Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works in both - Safari and Chrome on iOS - when using links of the style myFile.PDF#21
However for some reason it only works on the second try, i.e. when you open up the PDF it still shows the first page. You then have to manually enter another page number in the address bar and it will open this page. When you now change it back to your original page number it opens this one.

This looks very odd to me and is far from being applicable in a real environment.